# Fixing an incorrect answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, new-users

I just saw a (very...) common question on SO, so I copied an answer from the PHP documentation with link.

Trouble is, I misremembered what the example did (remove *excess* whitespace vs. removing *all* whitespace as the poster had requested), and didn't notice this until a couple of commenters went, "Hey!  WTF!"  There's a moral in here somewhere about the dangers of copy+paste.

Is it appropriate in this situation to edit the answer with a remark to this effect?  I don't want the incorrect version floating around there to mislead people who don't look at it too closely, but it also seems kind of... I dunno... unfair to the commenters (because I can just picture future commenters saying, "You guys are wrong!  It clearly removes all whitespace!").

Comment: Just a side note: 'Common' questions (means it was asked repeatedly) should be marked as duplicates instead of being answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I tend to do in this situation is either:

- Delete the answer (if its really really wrong, and someone else has posted the correct answer already)
- Edit the answer to be correct, and post a comment along the lines of "I've fixed it now..."

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's kind of fun getting all those commenters frowned upon. :)

No, but seriously, there will be a "edited on " at the bottom of the answer, so it'll be easy to tell that it must have been edited before. Only the new users would probably think otherwise.

Whenever a comment is there which points to a mistake which doesn't exist anymore, I assume that it had been there before, and it was then corrected.

If you're not as evil as I am, though, you could do what @Kragen suggested earlier.